# Sklearn: .predict returns an error Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed sklearn with pip and when I use the function .predict it returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Roberto/PycharmProjects/AI projects/New.py", line 8, in <module>
print(clf.predict([150, 0]))
File "C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 412, in predict
X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
File "C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 373, in _validate_X_predict
X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
File "C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 441, in check_array
"if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 150.    0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

And my code is:

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([150, 0]))
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you read the error message and try to do what they tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a single sample, if you pass [[150,0]] there will be no problem, like this:

```
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The hint is in the error message: "...if it contains a single sample." 
The problem is that in general a list of samples to predict is expected rather than just one. The data passed to `predict` should be in the same format as the `features` passed to `fit`, i.e. a 2-D array. Try

```
clf.predict([[150, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```